# typescript: pushing a NavController inside of setInterval(function() {})

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to listen to email verification, and redirect the user to another page as soon as they verify their email. Everything seems to work except for the redirection part, because I can't reference

```
this.navCtrl
```

inside of

```
setInterval(function() {})
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this otherwise? This is the full code which I'm running at the moment.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  // sending the verification email
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
    // verification send
  }, function(error) {
    // error sending ver
    console.error(error);
  });

  // listening to the verification and redirecting the user
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    setInterval(function () {
      firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
      if (firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) {
        console.log("Email Verified!");
        // this here is causing errors due to it being called here. 
        // I understand why it's causing errors, but I don't know 
        // how to fix this. The error currently reads: 
        // Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined
        this.navCtrl.setRoot("HomePage");
      }
    }, 1000);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context (`this`) will be lost when you use the `function() {}` syntax for callbacks. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will capture the correct context:

```
setInterval(() => {
    // `this` will be bound to the current class instance here
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But is there a difference between using the fat arrow `=>` or calling the `function() {}` syntax? As in, why should I ever **not** use the fat arrow?

Comment: A few cases I can think of: 1. compatibility -- fat arrows are not supported in older version of browsers. In these cases you can set the correct context by using [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) 2. When you actually want the context to change. ex: jQuery callbacks for `$().each`.